# Exception handling and recovering from non-fatal errors

Tags: c++, exception

I'm writing a C++ application which needs to deal with error codes from a C API, specifically the WinSock2 API. I'm not sure of the best way to handle fatal errors vs non-fatal errors.

For example, if my call to `send()` fails with error code `WSAECONNABORTED`, I want to return the error to the caller, but continue program execution. In this case the caller will mark the connection as terminated and carry on. But if it fails with an error I'd like to consider fatal, such as `WSAENETDOWN`, I want the application to terminate.

I know that exceptions are used for "exceptional" situations, so it makes sense to use exceptions to handle the fatal error case. What I'm questioning is how to handle the non-fatal error cases.

Should I return an error code in the non-fatal cases? If I also need to return a value, I'll need to return both a code (potentially success) and a value. Or should I make two exception classifications, something like `FatalError` and a `NonFatalError` classes, and only attempt recovery when handling the `NonFatalError` exceptions? Or are there other/better ways to do this?

**[Updated] Clarification**
There seems to be some confusion as to what I'm getting at with the original question. I Understand how exceptions are handled, what happens when they're not, rethrowing exceptions, and their performance characteristics.

I'm asking for techniques/best practices to handle situations which aren't really "exceptional". In this case, errors that may occur that cause a connection to become unusable, but do not impact the rest of the server.

Preferably I'd avoid having an exception class per error code, since that would create a lot of mostly useless exception classes.

Comment: Use `throw;` in your catch clause if you don't want to handle it.  Without any backstop, that ends the program through terminate().  Bam, dead, no hint to the user.

Comment: "Exceptions vs return codes" is quite orthogonal to "Is it fatal or not".

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions if you want to propagate the error up the callstack. Create your custom classes, which inherit from std::exception, and catch them if you want to apply a specific treatment.

```
try {
  my_function_which_throws();
} catch (const FatalError& e) {
  // do something, or rethrow
} catch (const NonFatalError& e) {
  // log or do nothing
}
```

exceptions only take time to handle if they are thrown. If your function don't throw anything, it won't impact performance.